# How to use the jQuery keyup event to modify the value of HTML inputs

Tags: jquery, input

I have 3 HTML inputs. When modifying the text in input 1, input 2 should update with the text that was previously in input 1. Input 3 should similarly update with the text that was previously in input 2.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Please try to improve your English. It is not clear what you want.

Comment: I think it would be better if you take some courses in English language before learning Web programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HYTcG/)**

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="someclass" />
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="someclass" />
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="someclass" />​

$('.someclass').change(function(){
   $(this).next('.someclass').val($(this).val()); 
   $(this).next('.someclass').change();
});​
```

Binding keyup event will change as soon as you type something

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HYTcG/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set the input values as desired.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#input1").keyup(function() {
            $('#input2').val($('#input1').val());
            $('#input3').val($('#input2').val());
        });
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <input type="text" id="input1" />
    <input type="text" id="input2" />
    <input type="text" id="input3" />
 </body>
</html>
```